# Malformed Lambda proxy response: deploying python endpoints through serverless

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am trying to send a JSON response back through a Lambda function (building through Serverless), but it is erroring out.

I am creating the response:

```
response = {}
response["file_name"] = file_name
response["status"] = status
response["description"] = message
response["data"] = data 
return {
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "body": json.dumps(response)
}
```

But AWS is only returning:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I am printing out that response object, and it is:

```
{'isBase64Encoded': False, 'statusCode': 200, 'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 'body': '{"file_name": "upload-4660557513950187006.csv", "status": "success", "description": "Success.", "data": ""}'}
```

When I invoke through API Gateway, this is the logs I am getting:

```
Thu Oct 05 16:21:15 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/parse","path":"/parse","httpMethod":"POST","headers":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"path":"/parse","accountId":"317910044022","resourceId":"xik9xe","stage":"test-invoke-stage","requestId":"test-invoke-request","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":"317910044022","cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":"AIDAJGNM4CLIWDKHDDV2U","apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","sourceIp":"test-invoke-source-ip","accessKey":"ASIAJHGYEQDHKLLRWL6A","cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::317910044022:user/chase","userAgent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_131)","user":"AIDAJGNM4CLIWDKHDDV2U"},"resourcePath":"/parse","httpMethod":"POST","apiId":"3gvwsa0cj2"},"body":"{\n\t\"file_name\": \"upload-4660557513950187006.csv\",\n\t\"vendor\": \"\"\n}","isBase64Encoded":false}
Thu Oct 05 16:21:15 UTC 2017 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:317910044022:function:PyParsingService-dev-parse/invocations
Thu Oct 05 16:21:16 UTC 2017 : Received response. Integration latency: 416 ms
Thu Oct 05 16:21:16 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\"isBase64Encoded\": false, \"statusCode\": 200, \"headers\": {\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\": \"*\", \"Content-Type\": \"application/json\"}, \"body\": \"{\\\"file_name\\\": \\\"upload-4660557513950187006.csv\\\", \\\"status\\\": \\\"success\\\", \\\"description\\\": \\\"Success.\\\", \\\"data\\\": \\\"\\\"}\"}"
Thu Oct 05 16:21:16 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, x-amzn-RequestId=36059915-a9e9-11e7-8444-438990db7407, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=317, Date=Thu, 05 Oct 2017 16:21:15 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-59d65bfb-7000702549081b6682b894a9;sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Thu Oct 05 16:21:16 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Thu Oct 05 16:21:16 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 502
```

Not very experienced with Python - any help would be greatly appreciated. According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) the response needs to be formatted properly for API Gateway. Not sure why my response isn't conforming to what API Gateway is looking for.

Comment: It may not be the issue with JSON. Can you try to invoke Lambda with an empty response? Just to make sure is it because of permission issue

Comment: What does your Cloudwatch Logs tell you? Is that how your actual code looks like? If so, then your Python code is getting syntax error due to incorrect indentation.

Comment: @dashmug I have included the logs in the original post. I am getting a "Malformed Lambda proxy response" error.

Comment: @Chase Are you using Lambda Proxy integration type? Are there errors in CloudWatch if you invoke it through an HTTP request (not using the API Gateway console)?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. The **Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response** error was referencing the response Lambda was trying to send back through API Gateway. Serverless automatically uses Lambda Proxy Integration. When I was looking at the response, I noticed extra escaping at the base response level (for instance, `"{\"isBase64Encoded\": false, \"statusCode\": 200, ...}`), which I believe was triggering the error. Sure enough, when I dug in deeper, I realized that I was dumping JSON (`json.dumps()`) after creating the response, which was throwing the error.

Thanks for the responses. Mindless mistake on my part.